# After Binded Spinner , How to Do not select first item?

Tags: java, android

```
public void DatabaseConn(){
DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
try { 
myDbHelper.createDataBase();  
} catch (IOException ioe) { 
throw new Error("Unable to create database"); 
}  
try {  
myDbHelper.openDataBase();         
}catch(SQLException sqle){  
throw sqle;  
}

SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
//SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/com.example.abc2/databases/DB_BusData", null, 0);
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Tbl_Driver", null);
startManagingCursor(c);
//create an array to specify which fields we want to display
String[] from = new String[]{"Driver_Name"};
//create an array of the display item we want to bind our data to
int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.text1};
//create simple cursor adapter
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, c, from, to );
adapter.setDropDownViewResource( android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item );
//get reference to our spinner
Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById( R.id.DriverSpin);
s.setAdapter(adapter);

db.close();
}
```

This is the code how i bind my Spinner with my DataBase,
But After Binded Spinner, will automatically selected first item,
i would like to let User select the Spinner by themself, how to do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SQLiteDatabase db = myDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
//SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase("/data/data/com.example.abc2/databases/DB_BusData", null, 0);
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Tbl_Vehicle", null);
//=====Add Additional=====
MatrixCursor extras = new MatrixCursor(new String[] { "_id", "Plat_No" });
extras.addRow(new String[] { "-1","< Select Vehicle >" });
Cursor[] cursors = { extras, c };
c = new MergeCursor(cursors);
//===========================
```

Just Add the First Items as blank or i have added "< Select Vehicle >" as the first item

Answer (score 0):

read this documentation page: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html

Comment: Seen before, but no idea how to do

Comment: what about "Sets the currently selected item." ?

Comment: of course it woeks as its the only way to change the selected item (-1 is not valid position)

Comment: read my question carefully, i want the spinner is blank and let user select them self

Comment: its not possuble to have "unknown" position, make the first item "blank" one

Answer (score 0):

Just add a default selection after populating the spinner something like --select driver-- then do a check in your listener to not do anything when the spinner position is 0

Comment: Chin I'm on my phone just add it to the array at first index then in your listener if(position!=0)